# Customise default 'New Stored Procedure' SSMS 2008 Template

Tags: sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, templates, ssms

I am trying to customise the default query which is put in place when you click `New Stored Procedure...` from the `Object Explorer` on SQL Server Management Studio 2008.

I have found how to change the 'Create Stored Procedure (New Menu)' template from the `Template Explorer`, however this means I will have to keep opening the template explorer rather than clicking on new stored procedure like i usually would.

How can I edit the template which appears when you click `New Stored Procedure...` ?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

For SQL Server 2008, find this directory :

`C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\VSShell\Common7\IDE\SqlWorkbenchProjectItems\Sql\Stored Procedure\`

or for those on x64 Windows,

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\VSShell\Common7\IDE\SqlWorkbenchProjectItems\Sql\Stored Procedure\`

Within are 6 .sql files:

- Alter
- Create Basic
- Create with Cursor
- Create with Output
- Create from New Menu
- Drop

Edit as you like!

**For SQL Server 2012**,

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio\SqlWorkbenchProjectItems\Sql\Stored Procedure`

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I get this far (see below), then I am just presented with 7 different .dll files. I don't know whether its because I'm using Windows 7? Thanks.

C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\VSShell\Common7\IDE

Comment: @Curt: I've updated after some research around 64 bit installations. Hope this solves your problem.

Comment: When I try to edit these files (within SQL Server 2012), I get an "access denied" error, even if I stop the SQL Server service.  Any ideas?

Comment: @Octavient try editing the file in an editor run as administrator.

Answer (score 4):

Works for SSMS 2005 and 2008:

In the menu click View/Template Explorer (or Ctrl-Alt-T)

Within the Template Explorer which opens, find:

Stored Procedure/Create Stored Procedure (New Menu)

**Edit:** Additional explanation

Right click and choose Edit in the popup menu to alter the file directly.

Comment: But this doesn't change the template which appears when you click New Stored Procedure...

Comment: @Colin It does if you right-click and choose edit in the popup menu.

Comment: That's what I did, but it didn't work for me. On my machine the template explorer is editing a file in this folder - C:\Users\Colin\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Shell\Templates\Sql\Stored Procedure but the right-click gets it from the folder in the accepted answer

Comment: @Colin strange, it works on every computer I can access, and probably the upvoters', too.

Answer (score 2):

For anyone interested, the files for SQL Server 2014 x64 are at:

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio\SqlWorkbenchProjectItems\Sql\Stored Procedure`

Comment: And for SQL Server 2016 `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio\SqlWorkbenchProjectItems\Sql\Stored Procedure`

Comment: For SQL Serevr 2016 I didn't find any directory inside ManagementStudio folder.

Comment: Might be C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\140\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio\SqlWorkbenchProjectItems\Sql\Stored Procedure for SQL Server 2016

Answer (score 2):

For SSMS 18 the file is located here:

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 18\Common7\IDE\SqlWorkbenchProjectItems\Sql\Stored Procedure`

Answer (score 1):

Seems there are TWO separated sets of scripts installing `SQL SMO 2005`: At the beginning they are usual, but think about this:

First set, is where p.campbell said (`C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\` etc) but the template used when you open the template manager are in `C:\docs & settings\myuser` etc; and this is quite logical: I don't want to find my collegues' customizations in my templates!.

I think that if you want to use a template "automatically" (right click, "create procedure") the template in `c:\program`... will be used while if you use the template manager, YOUR copy will be used instead.

PS: Thanks to all spending some of their time to help others!!